# How to add New Custom button in magento 2 product page

Tags: magento2

How can i add new button on magento 2 product page above add to cart button (as shown in the attached picture)

[image: agento2]

Comment: You want to display that button after price, Am I Right ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Yes after the price

Comment: Okay. Sending you solution after few mins

Comment: oky Thanks kishan  for helping me with the magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two files for that

first you need to add `catalog_product_view.xml` file here in this path in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.custombutton" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custombutton.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info.custombutton" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
    </body>
</page>
```

- After adding above xml file you need to create one template file here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custombutton.phtml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php echo "Custom Button here.."; ?>
```

You can change content based on your requirement.

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this answer will help you and you achieve your requirement then accept the answer . :)

Comment: Kishan is there any specific way to design a button or simple can we user <button> tag as html way

Comment: You can use <button> tag there.

Comment: I didn't have time yet to try that. asap i let u know

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<button title="Add to Cart" class="custom-button">
    <span>Custom Button</span>
</button>
<div class="product-add-form">
    <form data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSubmitUrl($_product)) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()) :?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= (int)$_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item"  value="<?= (int)$block->getRequest()->getParam('id') ?>" />
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_top') ?>
        <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()) :?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
        <?php else :?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1') :?>
                <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2') :?>
            <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom') ?>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'priceBox'
    ], function($){
        var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
            dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getId()) ?>]',
            priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

[image]